# Induction on the center of solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid, induction

Why is the magnetic induction at the middle of the solenoid greater than at the end of the solenoid?

I know it's bigger, but the question is why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by `magnetic induction` and how is it relevant to a solenoid? What do you mean by `middle of the solenoid`?

Comment: and the answer for anything related to induction is always going to be "because of physics, specifically Ampère's circuital law as part of Maxwell's Equations". So, do you know Ampère's law?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[The magnetic H field lines diverge at both ends and thus less concentrated.](http://www.falstad.com/vector3dm/vector3dm.html?f=CurrentLoopsStackedField&d=streamlines&sl=none&st=20&ld=5&a1=40&a2=10&a3=1&rx=72&ry=0&rz=0&zm=1.2)

[image]
Above with just 2 loops of current.